# wilcard DNS and Virtual subdomains?

Tags: php, virtual, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I just don't get it..

I'm planning to get scenario like this: username.mydomain.com = mydomain.com/user.php?user=username

Well, let's not go that far yet because this wildcard DNS is making me insane!! :/

I have DNS record

```
* A my-ip-address
```

And I have in my vhost file

```
ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
```

But it just doesn't work at all.. No wait, example test.mydomain.com is working but not any random subdomain.. Wut?

When I ping any subdomain it find my ip like it should be. Can anyone help me?

Okey and then this other issue. When (and if) I'll get this virtual subdomain working, what would be best sollution to make it work like I explained above?

username.mydomain.com equals to mydomain.com/user.php?user=username

but user can see it just like it would be subdomain... Little lost here, sry! :)

Thanks for all help!

Comment: when you say .. it doesnt work ..... what part exactly doesnt work?

Comment: Oh yes, server not found.. But it's really weird that test.mydomain.com does work.. really weird..

Comment: ok just to be sure .. i always have someone else on the outside check when it comes to dns stuff .. check with network-tools.com and see if it pings the place correctly and also check in their header check and see what it gets.

Comment: This seems to be more a system configuration issue than programming related. I wonder if you'd get more help over on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

just dealt with the same exact situation

what you need to do is

- go to Advanced DNS Zone Editor in cpanel
- select the domain
- name : *.doaminname.com
- TTL : 14400
- Type: CNAME
- Address : domainname.com/path
- So, it would be like:  *.doaminname.com CNAME 14400 domainname.com/path

and then a little tweak in .htaccess

```
# Extract the subdomain part of domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domainname\.com$ [NC]

# Check that the subdomain part is not www and ftp and mail
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]

# Redirect all requests to a php script passing as argument the subdomain
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domainname.com/path/%1 [R,L]
```

here %1 is the subdomain bit.

hope, this helps some body other lost in this case. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i just realized it .... i always use..

- CNAME abc.com.

http://www.decodephp.com/2006/10/12/virtual-subdomains-and-php/

Comment: thats not a bullet its "* CNAME abc.com."

Comment: Okey, I changed to CNAME and tested ping via network-tools.com. It pings for every single random subdomain but when I try to access whit browser: Problem loading page, server not found.. I don't know if these help but I'm in VPS, served by slicehost and I use cPanel VPS optimized.. Something is cleary blocking access there??

Comment: no i dont think so .. just restart ur bind and then also can u post the vhost entry from httpd.conf here ... just to make sure? also make sure whenever ur testing with a random string .. make sure its unique everytime .. cause ur local os will cache the lookup results from previous lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I don't know what just happend but I get really mad about this situation, nuked my VPS and re-install whole system... and now it is working.. :)

Anyways, thanks Sab!